# ap div z index - change on hover?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a series of ap divs stacked like an untidy pile of photos. I want a visitor to be able to click on a photo in that stack and for the photo to be on top of the stack.
This is what I have for each ap div:

```
#apDiv6 {
position:absolute;
width:180px;
height:172px;
z-index:1;
top: 90px;
left: 377px;}
```

I'd like to know what code I can add to change the z index of the clicked image in an ap div.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the z-index of the currently selected div to a higher value:

```
var z = 10;  //Declare it as global variable

function ShowDiv() {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = z;
  z++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Would I just put that in the head? Do I alter the code for the ap divs at all?

Comment: You can use this code as it is. But you need to cal the function ShowDiv() on your Button click event.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand where I add the code. Here are some of my divs which on the page appear as a jumbled pile of pictures.  <div id="apDiv2"><a href="work_offside.html"><img src="img/offside_front.png" width="200" height="162" border="0" /></a></div>
  <div id="apDiv5"><a href="work_yunomi.html"><img src="img/yunomi_front.png" width="173" height="157" border="0" /></a></div>
<div id="apDiv6"><img src="img/comics_link.png" alt="Comics" width="180" height="172" border="0" /></div>  Thanks